# How to count values in dictionary and print the key and value associated with the max amount

Tags: python, dictionary, max, anagram

I have created an anagram program that takes all words from a file and prints the letters followed by all of the words from the file that can be created using those letters. This is an example of what it prints out:

```
cinos ['cions', 'coins', 'icons', 'scion', 'sonic']
```

Now that I have created an anagram program that has a dictionary with the random letters as keys and the anagrams as values, I want to find the group of letters(keys) that has the largest amount of anagrams(values) and print just the values. Here is what I have written:

```
from collections import defaultdict

f= open('dictionary.txt')
d= defaultdict(list)
for line in f:
    strip=line.rstrip()
    key = "".join(sorted(strip))
    d[key].append(strip)
count=0
for values in d.values():
    if len(values)>count:
        count=len(values)
        print(values)
```

This prints all of the values ever assigned to count, but I just want to print the last entry associated in count. I tried values[-1], but that didn't work.

Comment: Can we see the whole stack trace, please? I could probably inspect your code for a while and figure out what's causing the error, but it would be easier if you just pasted the whole error.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you expect

```
count="".count(values)
```

to do, but Python is trying to interpret it as "count the number of times the string object referenced by the name `values` appears within the string object `''`", which is coming to an inevitable and unsuccessful end as `values` isn't a string object and `''` is empty anyway.

Comment: I changed it to len(values)

Comment: Well now you're trying to find `max(len(values))`; how could you possibly find the largest value of a single value? `max` expects something it can iterate over, comparing the sizes of the objects it contains, but you're giving it a single value.

Comment: Ok changed everything again. Is that better?

Answer (score 2):

```
d = { "taf": ["aft", "fat"], ... }
max_d = max(d.values(), key=len)
```

I think this is what you're trying to do. You have some dictionary `d` of random letters as keys, with their possible anagrams as a list of values. Your goal is to return the key with the LONGEST list of values, right?

That said, this seems INCREDIBLY memory intensive. If I were you, I'd do this instead:

```
lst_of_random_letters = ["abcdef", "abcdeg", "abcdeh" ... ] # however you're generating this
def make_anagrams(letters):
    # however you're implementing this
    # but return a list of the anagrams, e.g.
    # [IN] : cions
    # [OUT]: ['cions', 'coins', 'icons', 'scion', 'sonic']

longest_anagrams = max((make_anagrams(letters) for letters in lst_of_random_letters), key=len)
```

Comment: No I need to return just the values that are associated with that key. The values contain the anagrams and that is all I want to list.

Comment: @user3617808 Oh you did say that in your question, sorry I misread. I've edited both code snippets to reflect that change.

Comment: I edited the for loop again and for the most part it works. Just trying to figure out how to tell it to just print the last list of values associated with count instead of all of the lists.

Comment: @user3617808 Think very hard about what your code does in that for loop. How are you saving the largest value? ARE you saving it? SHOULD you be? Also: why are you even DOING this with a for loop? This is what `max` is literally built for.

Answer (score 1):

your error is caused by:

```
count="".count(values)
```

to which you give `values` which has been defined as a list in:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
```

as the help page of `count` states:

```
count(...)
    S.count(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

    Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in
    string S[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are
    interpreted as in slice notation.
```

it's unlikely to work.

instead prefer:

```
largest_group = max(d, key=lambda x: len(d[x]))
```

as suggested by @AdamSmith (disclaimer: I was about to write the same thing as you posted your answer)

Comment: No disclaimer needed. I was confused by his method and discarded it whole-cloth, which is probably not the best approach when we're trying to teach :D. However I'd made a typo in my answer -- `max(d, key=lambda x: len(d[x]))` is the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

This calls `len` on each value and returns the longest value

```
max(d.values(), key=len)
```

If 2 or more values have the same length, you'll still just get one of them