# How to print the longest dictionary value?

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I have a dictionary whose values are all lists of strings and I want to print the longest value(in this case, the list with the most strings). I created this for loop:

```
count=0
for values in d.values():
    if len(values)>count:
        count=len(values)
        print(values)
```

However, this prints all of the values ever associated with 'count'. I only want the largest one (which is the last line). This is an example of what the for loop prints:

```
['gul', 'lug']
['tawsed', 'wadset', 'wasted']
['lameness', 'maleness', 'maneless', 'nameless', 'salesmen']
['pores', 'poser', 'prose', 'repos', 'ropes', 'spore']
['arrest', 'rarest', 'raster', 'raters', 'starer', 'tarres', 'terras']
['carets', 'cartes', 'caster', 'caters', 'crates', 'reacts', 'recast', 'traces']
['estrin', 'inerts', 'insert', 'inters', 'niters', 'nitres', 'sinter', 'triens', 'trines']
['least', 'setal', 'slate', 'stale', 'steal', 'stela', 'taels', 'tales', 'teals', 'tesla'] 
['apers', 'apres', 'asper', 'pares', 'parse', 'pears', 'prase', 'presa', 'rapes', 'reaps', 'spare', 'spear']
```

How can I get it to print only that last(longest) line?

Comment: How long have you spent on the problem?

Comment: This is a continuation [of his last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553157/how-to-count-values-in-dictionary-and-print-the-key-and-value-associated-with-th)

Comment: I spent about 30 minutes trying to find similar issues, but couldn't Most were just answers on how to print the length as a number, not on how to print the values associated with it. I have tried different ways of indenting print(values) and I have not been successful.

Comment: @AdamSmith, a continuation .... you mean a DUPE !?!?! Release the hounds!!

Comment: @dilbert it's like diablo 1 all over again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspired by Dilbert there is a chance for simplification, no need to use `lambda` to define function for comparing values, we may take advantage of the fact, that `len` returns length of each item and this is perfect key for deciding who comes first and who is last:

```
print sorted(d.values(), key=len)[-1]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why we're sorting this though. `max` is better.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your's worked perfectly once I dedented it all the way to the left.

Comment: @user3617808 except by implementing this you've made your code O(2n) but okay......

Comment: Hah! It seems I've forgotten about `max` and `key=`.

Comment: I agree, that `max` is better, I was about to make that edit, but Totem was a bit faster.

Answer (score 11):

```
max(d.values(), key=len)
```

This prints out the longest list of words from your dict values. I used the `max()` function, which takes a `key` parameter that is assigned to the function `len`(in this case). Basically, the criteria for which value is the 'max' value is now decided by it's `len`.

Comment: This is what I suggested [on his last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553157/how-to-count-values-in-dictionary-and-print-the-key-and-value-associated-with-th)

Answer (score 1):

```
count = 0
for values in d.values():
    if len(values) > count:
        values_with_largest_count_first_hit = values
print(values_with_largest_count_first_hit)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print sorted(d.values(), cmp = lambda x, y: cmp(len(x), len(y)))[-1]
```

Comment: why sort this when you can use `max(d.values(), key=len)` ?

Comment: That's true, I forgot about both `max` and `key=`. I typically don't want a single value though (ie: largest); force of habit.